# Max value from Member Property

Tags: max, ssas, mdx

I need to get the max value of a member property to use in another `MDX` expression.

As an example from Adventure Works I'm using the following

```
 WITH 
  MEMBER DoFP AS 
    [Customer].[Customer].Properties("Date of First Purchase") 
  MEMBER MaxDoFP AS 
    Tail
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [Date].[Date].[Date]
       ,[Measures].[DoFP]
      )
     ,1
    ).Item(0).MemberValue 
SELECT 
  [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year] ON 0
 ,{
    [Customer].[Customer].&[20075]
   ,[Customer].[Customer].&[15568]
   ,[Customer].[Customer].&[20285]
  } ON 1
FROM [Adventure works]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[DoFP];
```

I'd like it to return June 15, 2008 for all rows/cols which is the date of first purchase for Aaron Alexander (who has the max DoFP of the customers selected) so that I can do some more calcs.  Instead its giving me 31st Dec 2010 because (I assume) that's the last date in my [Date].[Date].[Date].

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty:

```
WITH 
  SET X AS 
    {
      [Customer].[Customer].&[20075]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].&[15568]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].&[20285]
    } 
  MEMBER DoFP AS 
    [Customer].[Customer].Properties("Date of First Purchase") 
  MEMBER MaxDoFP1 AS 
    Max(DoFP) 
  MEMBER MaxDoFP2 AS 
    Max
    (
      X
     ,Cdate([Customer].[Customer].Properties("Date of First Purchase"))
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year] ON 0
 ,
  X * {[Measures].[MaxDoFP1],[Measures].[MaxDoFP2]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure works];
```

Comment: Don't mind about not pretty:)!  Will this work for a user-defined set?  The users will be querying the data from and Excel PT and selecting the customers themselves?

Comment: My initial instinct is that it might struggle - test it out and let me know. Create the named set and measures and see what happens. Are you using `2013` with the ability to add custom measures to PT?

Comment: (p.s. pretty is important)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the help.  Unfortunately we are using 2010. Will test in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (assuming you have the ability to extend the cube structure) would be to create a measure group based on the customer dimension using a MAX aggregation function. I imagine performance would be a bit better for larger sets.

```
WITH 
  SET X AS 
    {
      [Customer].[Customer].&[20075]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].&[15568]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].&[20285]
    } 
  MEMBER MaxDoFP AS 
    Max (X,[Measures].[Customer DoFP MAX]) 
SELECT 
  [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year] ON 0
 ,X * {[Measures].[MaxDoFP]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure works];
```